# A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again

Tags: php, magento, magento2

i have created a module for creating a Quick order so customer can place there order without registering or login. i am getting 5 fields from customers to process their order and its working fine. i have debug the code below and its working fine except 
`$order_id = $cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId());` this line of code is getting error of **A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.** i dont know the issue right now and looking for quick solution. when i try to check the log i found the following error 

{"0":"A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.","1":"

```
#1 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('placeOrder', array(11804, NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#2 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(11804, NULL) called at [vendor/magento/module-braintree/Plugin/OrderCancellation.php:63]\n#3 Magento\Braintree\Plugin\OrderCancellation->aroundPlaceOrder(&Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor#0000000068771282000000001567ed28#, &Closure#0000000068771726000000001567ed28#, 11804) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#4 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(11804) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#5 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('placeOrder', array(11804), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement/Interceptor.php:26]
```

`namespace QuickOrder\QuickBuy\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

class CustomOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_helper;
    //protected $_data;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \QuickOrder\QuickBuy\Helper\Data $helper)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
$email = "demo@demo.com";
$fname = "fname";
$lname = "lname";
$password = "password";
$product_id = 1036;


$object = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $object->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$customerFactory = $object->get('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$cartManagementInterface = $object->get('Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface');
$cartRepositoryInterface = $object->get('Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');
$customerRepository= $object->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$shippingRate= $object->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate');
$productFactory=$object->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

$customer=$customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->loadByEmail($email);

if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
    ->setStore($store)
    ->setFirstname($fname)
    ->setLastname($lname)
    ->setEmail($email)
    ->setPassword($password);
    $customer->save();
}

$cart_id = $cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
$cart = $cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart_id);
$cart->setStore($store);

$customer= $customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
$cart->setCurrency();
$cart->assignCustomer($customer);

$product = $productFactory->create()->load($product_id);
$cart->addProduct($product,1);

$orderData =[
    'currency_id'  => 'PKR',
    'email'        => 'test.magecomp@gmail.com', //buyer email id
    'shipping_address' =>[
        'firstname'    => 'John', //address Details
        'lastname'     => 'Deo',
        'street' => 'Main Street',
        'city' => 'Lahore',
        'country_id' => 'PK',
        'region' => 'Punjab',
        'postcode' => '85001',
        'telephone' => '823322565',
        'fax' => '3245845623',
        'shipping_method' => 'flatrate',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
    ],
    'items'=> [
        //array of product which order you want to create
        ['product_id'=>'1036','price'=> '899','qty'=>2]
    ]
];
$cart->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
$cart->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

$shippingRate->setCode('flatrate_flatrate')->getPrice(1);
$cart->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($shippingRate);
$cart->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery'); 
$cart->setInventoryProcessed(false);
$cart->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);
$cart->collectTotals();
$cart->save();
$cart = $cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart->getId());
$order_id = $cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId());

return $order_id;

    }
}`

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs?

Comment: yes i have attach the error log please check above the namespace #1 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('placeOrder', array(11804, NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]